# What does "ls --dired - l" or "ls -D -l" actually print?

Tags: linux, ls

`ls --dired -l` prints all dir and files along with some number followed by

```
//DIRED// ***66 69 122 131 ....***
//DIRED-OPTIONS// --quoting-style=literal
```

What do these numbers in bold mean?

`--dired` is an Emacs option to work with directories but I don't understand the numbers here.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The output of `ls -D` is meant to be parsed by Emacs' [dired mode](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/DiredMode).

From the [GNU Coreutils manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/What-information-is-listed.html)

> ```
> ‘-D’
> ‘--dired’
> ```
>
> With the long listing (`-l`) format, print an additional line after the main output:
>
> ```
> //DIRED// beg1 end1 beg2 end2 …
> ```
>
> The *begn* and *endn* are unsigned integers that record the byte position of the beginning and end of each file name in the output.
>   This makes it easy for Emacs to find the names, even when they contain
>   unusual characters such as space or newline, without fancy searching.
>
> If directories are being listed recursively (`-R`), output a similar line with offsets for each subdirectory name:
>
> ```
> //SUBDIRED// beg1 end1 …
> ```
>
> Finally, output a line of the form:
>
> ```
> //DIRED-OPTIONS// --quoting-style=word
> ```
>
> where word is the quoting style (see Formatting the file names).
>
> Here is an actual example:
>
> ```
> $ mkdir -p a/sub/deeper a/sub2
> $ touch a/f1 a/f2
> $ touch a/sub/deeper/file
> $ ls -gloRF --dired a
>   a:
>   total 8
>   -rw-r--r-- 1    0 Jun 10 12:27 f1
>   -rw-r--r-- 1    0 Jun 10 12:27 f2
>   drwxr-xr-x 3 4096 Jun 10 12:27 sub/
>   drwxr-xr-x 2 4096 Jun 10 12:27 sub2/
>
>   a/sub:
>   total 4
>   drwxr-xr-x 2 4096 Jun 10 12:27 deeper/
>
>   a/sub/deeper:
>   total 0
>   -rw-r--r-- 1 0 Jun 10 12:27 file
>
>   a/sub2:
>   total 0
> //DIRED// 48 50 84 86 120 123 158 162 217 223 282 286
> //SUBDIRED// 2 3 167 172 228 240 290 296
> //DIRED-OPTIONS// --quoting-style=literal
> ```
>
> Note that the pairs of offsets on the ‘//DIRED//’ line above delimit these names: f1, f2, sub, sub2, deeper, file. The offsets on
>   the ‘//SUBDIRED//’ line delimit the following directory names: `a`,
>   `a/sub`, `a/sub/deeper`, `a/sub2`.
>
> Here is an example of how to extract the fifth entry name, `deeper`, corresponding to the pair of offsets, 222 and 228:
>
> ```
> $ ls -gloRF --dired a > out
> $ dd bs=1 skip=222 count=6 < out 2>/dev/null; echo
> deeper
> ```
>
> Note that although the listing above includes a trailing slash for the `deeper` entry, the offsets select the name without the trailing
>   slash. However, if you invoke `ls` with `--dired` along with an option
>   like `--escape` (aka `-b`) and operate on a file whose name contains
>   special characters, notice that the backslash is included:
>
> ```
> $ touch 'a b'
> $ ls -blog --dired 'a b'
>   -rw-r--r-- 1 0 Jun 10 12:28 a\ b
> //DIRED// 30 34
> //DIRED-OPTIONS// --quoting-style=escape
> ```
>
> If you use a quoting style that adds quote marks (e.g., `--quoting-style=c`), then the offsets include the quote marks. So beware that the user may select the quoting style via the environment
>   variable `QUOTING_STYLE`. Hence, applications using `--dired` should
>   either specify an explicit `--quoting-style=literal` option (aka `-N` or
>   `--literal`) on the command line, or else be prepared to parse the escaped names.

The numbers are the positions of the file names in the output

> The begn and endn are unsigned integers that record the byte position of the beginning and end of each file name in the output.

Comment: Of course, there is no 222 in the `ls --dired` example quoted from the info page. But there is a 223. If one is supposed to subtract 1 from all offsets, that is not how it works in my tests

Answer (score 1):

-D, --dired
              generate output designed for Emacs' [dired mode](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/DiredMode).

Comment: what asked is --dired mode for "ls" command not for Emacs. Read the question carefully.

Comment: @sameerpradhan Yes the output of `ls` is made **for** Emacs.

Comment: @Matteo Yes. But see my question 1st. What i want to know the numbers below the output of "ls --dired -l" command.

Comment: @sameerpradhan The output is meant for Emacs, the suggestion to look at the Emacs documentation is correct.

Comment: @matteo :Again I am saying this, My question was : what are these numbers printed at the bottom of the output of "ls --dired -l" followed by //DIRED//.

Comment: @dave_alcarin This "answer" doesn't state anything useful. The OP asked "What do these numbers in bold mean?" and this doesn't even attempt to answer that. Matteo did finally read and comprehend the question, and posted a correct answer which the OP accepted.